# Reflection - Get the list of method calls inside a lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I am trying to find a way to get the list of method calls inside a lambda expression in C# 3.5. For instance, in the code below, I would like to method LookAtThis(Action a) to analyze the content of the lambda expression. In other words, I want LookAtThis to return me the MethodInfo object of Create.

```
LookAtThis(() => Create(null, 0));
```

Is it possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is fairly easy as long as you use `Expression<Action>` instead of `Action`. For full code, including how to get the actual values implied, [see here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.Extensions/ServiceModel/Client/ProtoClientExtensions.cs) - in particular `ResolveMethod` (and how it is used by `Invoke`). This is the code I use in protobuf-net to do RPC based on lambdas.

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

class Program
{
    static void Create(object o, int n) { Debug.Print("Create!"); }

    static void LookAtThis(Expression expression)
    {
        //inspect:
        MethodInfo method = ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method;
        Debug.Print("Method = '{0}'", method.Name);

        //execute:
        Action action = expression.Compile();
        action();
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        LookAtThis((Expression)(() => Create(null, 0)));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static MethodInfo GetMethodInfo<T>(Expression<Func<T>> expression)
{
    return ((MethodCallExpression)expression.Body).Method;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd need to use [Expression Trees](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx) instead. See [Expression Tree Visualizer Sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397975.aspx) and [How to: Implement an Expression Tree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb882521.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Practically speaking, no this is not possible with reflection.  Reflection is primarily aimed at providing meta data inspection information at runtime.  What you're asking for is actual code inspection information.

I believe it is possible to get the actual bytes representing the IL for a method at runtime.  However it would be just that, an array of bytes.  You would have to manually interpret this into IL opcodes and use that to determine what methods were called.  This is almost certainly not what you're looking for though.

It is possible though to use an expression tree lambda and analyze that for method calls.  However this cannot be done on any arbitrary lambda expression.  It must be done an an expression tree lambda expression.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

Comment: And even if you do get the **code** behind the lamdba, deciding whether or not the code will throw an exception (without actually executing it) is an NP-Complete problem.  it is _much_ easier to write self-protecting lambda expressions to avoid exceptions you don't want thrown.