# Use Lambda expressions as a parameter?

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to use the lambda expression in my Repository
as a generic parameter. If I use a firm like this one:

```
MyEntity entity:null

void Run(Expression<Func<MyEntity ,bool>> expression)
```

I can call it in this way:

```
Run(x => x.FirstName = "Whatever")
```

What I would like is the ability to do something like this:

```
Run(x => x.FirstName = "Whatever" and x.LastName = "whatelse")
```

or

```
Run(x => x.FirstName = "Whatever" && x.LastName = "whatelse")
```

And read the content of x.FirstName and x.LastName inside
the procedure Run. Is there a way to accomplish that?

Comment: It might help to tag this question with the language you're writing in.

Comment: Are you using assignment operators instead of equality tests? Otherwise, that last version looks fine.

Comment: it should be: Run(x => x.FirstName == "Whatever") the delegate expects a bool

Answer (score 4):

You have your Run method declared as:

```
void Run(Expression<Func<MyEntity ,bool>> expression)
```

This would just work if you just declared it as:

```
void Run(Func<MyEntity ,bool> expression)
```

Is there a reason you're taking an expression, and not just a delegate (`Func<MyEntity,bool>`) directly?

Comment: Reed, I imagine the poster is using Expressions to be able to inspect the expression within the Run method (i.e., not just execute it).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use

```
void Run(Action<MyEntity> action)
```

and then

```
Run(x => {x.FirstName = "Whatever"; x.LastName = "whatelse"})
```

since I don't see that you use return value.

Not sure if Expression<Action<MyEntity>> will work (if you need to inspect it) but you can try.

Comment: Yes but how I can read then the Action<MyEntity> assigned values?

Comment: Why don't you use this: { MyEntity tmp; action(tmp); if (tmp.FirstName)...} - if you don't want to affect your "working" entity.

Comment: Here's a link to example code of how you can parse Expression[Action]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717091/reflection-get-the-list-of-method-calls-inside-a-lambda-expression/717332#717332

Comment: I want to call this expression and fill with lamba expression the entity contained in the parameter

Then I want to evaluate the properties of the entity in the run procedure

Answer (score 0):

All, the reason why the OP is passing in an `Expression<Func<MyEntity, bool>>` parameter as opposed to a `Func<MyEntity, bool>` parameter is that he/she wants to inspect the expression itself within the Run method.

The Expression object has several properties that enable you to inspect the peculiars of the expression at runtime.  One of these, Body, can be used to discern the code used within the expression, while the Parameters collection can be used to inspect the type and order of parameters that can be passed to the expression when compiled.

```
Console.WriteLine(expression.Parameters[0].Type); //writes MyEntity
Console.WriteLine(expression.Body); 
   //writes ((x.FirstName == "Bob" && x.LastName == "Smith"))
```

In your example, you are defining an expression but you haven't actually called it.  Therefore, you haven't actually passed in a parameter (the MyEntity object) and so there aren't any arguments to inspect.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the following:

```
Run(x => (x.FirstName == "Whatever" && x.LastName == "whatelse"))
```

Comment: Yes it works but I want to know the value of x.FirstName inside the procedure run, how I can do that?