# Parsing Expressions as a parameter

Tags: c#, lambda

I'm trying to write a method which can be called like this:

```
var myCommand = Command.Where(x => x.Name == "grep" && x.Switch == "x");
```

What I'm trying to do is parse the resulting expression like so:

```
public static string FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>>  expression)
{
    var condition1Key = ? //condition1Key = "Name"
    var condition1Value = ? //condition1Value = "grep"
    var condition2Key = ? //condition1Key = "Switch"
    var condition2Value = ? //condition1Value = "x"
    
   return string.Format("Looking for commands with {0} = {1} and {2} = {3}",
                         condition1Key, condition1Value, 
                         condition2Key, condition2Value);
}
```

I did find [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1473289/use-lambda-expressions-as-a-parameter) but it is quite old and never received a proper answer.

#### How can I parse the incoming `Expression` to pull out what I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you follow the links in the SO thread you mentioned, you arrive at the [MSDN entry for expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx).  Particularly, under the "Parsing Expression Trees" section, the following example should help:

```
// Create an expression tree.
Expression<Func<int, bool>> exprTree = num => num < 5;

// Decompose the expression tree.
ParameterExpression param = (ParameterExpression)exprTree.Parameters[0];
BinaryExpression operation = (BinaryExpression)exprTree.Body;
ParameterExpression left = (ParameterExpression)operation.Left;
ConstantExpression right = (ConstantExpression)operation.Right;

Console.WriteLine("Decomposed expression: {0} => {1} {2} {3}",
              param.Name, left.Name, operation.NodeType, right.Value);

// This code produces the following output:
// Decomposed expression: num => num LessThan 5
```

You can even create a class to make the walking on the tree easier: [How to: Implement an Expression Tree Visitor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb882521.aspx)

Comment: For my particular example I had to change `ParameterExpression` to `MemberExpression` and `left.Name` to `left.Member.Name`. Otherwise works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can parse the `Expression` tree. Here's a basic example from MSDN:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397951.aspx

And more from a blog post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/charlie/archive/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics.aspx

And a great answer on here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/239359/29093