# How to validate lambda expressions against null references?

Tags: c#, lambda, nullreferenceexception

I have a method that accepts a generic delegate as a parameter, and inserts it in a list:

```
public void AddFilterMember<T>(Func<T, bool> filterMember)
{
    filter.Add(filterMember);
}
```

Later on all delegates are invoked over an instance of type **T** to find out if this instance passes the filter, i.e, if **true** is returned for every **filterMember** invoked.

I noticed that it is possible to pass an invalid lambda expression like the following:

```
string str = null;
AddFilterMember(x => str.Contains((string)x));
```

Which obviously will throw an exception when invoked because the **str** string is null. So I would like to know the best way to validate a lambda expression against null references (other than its parameters) at the moment it is defined?

I guess one option would be to invoke it using a default instance of T, but sometimes this is not feasible because T may not have a default parameterless constructor.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Checking `str` for `null` beforehand is probably the only good way. Is there a reason you can't do this?

Comment: @minitech: My idea would be to throw an exception notifying a user that forgot to do the null checking himself.

Comment: A user that forgot to do the null checking is notified: he gets a NullReferenceException

Comment: Yeah, but that will happen only when the expression is invoked, which may occur long after he created the delegate. I would like to save him some time telling it is invalid at the moment he calls **AddFilterMember**...

Comment: @dtb `NullReferenceException` is probably not the best exception to throw, `ArgumentNullException` should be thrown instead

Comment: @ThomasC.G.deVilhena What if the string is null at the moment the `AddFilterMember` and is not when the code is actually executed?

Comment: In this case a valid delegate would then become invalid... Maybe another point to consider :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a possible solution:

```
public bool AddFilterMember<T>(Func<T, bool> filterMember, T checkValue = default(T))
{
    try
    {
        filterMember(checkValue);
    }
    catch
    {
        return false;
    }
    filter.Add(filterMember);
    return true;
}
```

If the caller knows that `default(T)` won't work, but expects all actually-used values to work, they can specify the `checkValue` to be an example.  From there, you just try to run the delegate and see if it works or not.  A `bool` is returned to let the caller know whether it was successfully done or not.

Note that invoking the delegate can cause side effects.  The behavior of this should be documented so callers aren't surprised.

Answer (score 1):

I usually do that this way:

```
AddFilterMember(
     x => {
           if(str == null) 
             throw new ArgumentNullException("str cannot be null");                     
           str.Contains((string)x)
          });
```

Comment: I like this answer.  It is basically **Write smarter filter lambdas.**  Thomas, the only other choice I see is to put a try..catch around the invocation of each FilterMember in your list.

Answer (score 0):

Related question and possible answer:

[Reflection - Get the list of method calls inside a lambda expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717091/reflection-get-the-list-of-method-calls-inside-a-lambda-expression)

But without try..catch around an actual execution, it is an NP-complete problem to decide whether or not a lambda expression is going to throw later on.

Especially if, like in your example, the lambda refers to a variable that may or may not be null each time the expression is executed.  If the lambda doesn't check, then it might throw.

**re: some T don't have a default value.**

Perhaps a cast: `(T)null` for the `try..catch` test of the lambda, since you were specifically asking about `NullReferenceException`.

-Jesse

Comment: All `T` do have a default value.  You can get this by `default(T)`.  For reference types, this is null, and for value types it is 0, false, or for `struct`s, equivalent to `new T()`.  What you mean is that there is not always a default parameterless constructor, `new T()`.  If it makes sense to do so, you can actually specify `where T : new()` to say that it must have a default paramaterless constructor.  Much simpler than just trying to use `Activator.CreateInstance` and see if it works at runtime.

Comment: @TimS - Thank you for that correction.  That is indeed what I meant. `default(T)` assumes the parameterless constructor is available.